# Choosing eigenvectors and eigenvalues continuously

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H=L^2(X)$ for some compact space $X$. We denote by $U(H)$ the space of unitary operators on $H$ with the topology induced by the operator norm.

> Given a continuous map $t\mapsto S_t$ from $[0,1]$ to $U(H)$. Is there a continuous (or at least Borel) maps $t\mapsto \lambda_t$ and $t\mapsto f_t$ the first with values in $S^1$ and the second with values in $H\backslash\{0\}$ such that $S_t f_t =\lambda_t f_t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unitary operator need not have any eigenvectors at all.  For instance, let $X=S^1$ with its usual measure, and let $S\in U(H)$ be defined by $S(f)(z)=zf(z)$ (so, $S$ is the multiplication operator for the inclusion function $S^1\to \mathbb{C}$).  Then if $f\in H$ is such that $S(f)=\lambda f$ for some scalar $f$, this means $zf(z)=\lambda f(z)$ almost everywhere.  But this implies $f(z)=0$ almost everywhere (since if $f(z)\neq 0$ and $zf(z)=\lambda f(z)$ we can only have $z=\lambda$), so $f=0$ in $H$.

So, if $S_t$ is this $S$ for all $t$, then your desired $f_t$ and $\lambda_t$ do not exist.

Comment: Thank you! But now I don't know whether this holds if we assume that there exists an eigenvalue. Do you suggest to write another question in this case?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest posting that as a new question.  If you want the maps to be continuous then the answer is definitely no, even in the finite-dimensional case (consider a case where $S_t$ has distinct eigenvalues for all $t<1/2$, $S_{1/2}$ is the identity, and then $S_t$ has distinct eigenvalues again for $t>1/2$ but the eigenvectors change abruptly from what they were for $t<1/2$).  I don't know what can be said if you just want Borel maps though.

Comment: Will do. I read somewhere (maybe for finite dimensional) that the eigenvalues of normal matrices are stable under continuous mapping. If so then you can't construct such an example.